# Android Wear: MainActivity cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener

Tags: java, android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I am trying to get my Android Wear 2.0 device's location, using the example [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/wear-location-detection.html). I have imported:

```
com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest
com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices
```

But I am receiving the error:

```
01-26 00:08:24.508 15589-15589/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.buschecker.williamvenner.buschecker, PID: 15589
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.buschecker.williamvenner.buschecker.MainActivity$4 cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
   at com.buschecker.williamvenner.buschecker.MainActivity.onConnected(MainActivity.java:166)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzm.zzq(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaal.zzo(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaaj.zzvE(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaaj.onConnected(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaan.onConnected(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzzy.onConnected(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzl$1.onConnected(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zzj.zzwZ(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zza.zzu(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zze.zzxa(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zzd.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I really don't know what to do, I'm not importing `android.location.LocationServices`, I'm importing `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices` so it doesn't make sense as to why I'm receiving this error as Googling tells me to switch between the two libraries.

Here's my full code:

```
package com.buschecker.williamvenner.buschecker;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.wearable.activity.WearableActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Result;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private String TransportAPI_ID  = "XXX";
    private String TransportAPI_Key = "XXX";

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private ListView bus_stops;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> bus_stops_adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setAmbientEnabled();

        bus_stops = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.bus_stop_list);

        String[] items = {"Loading..."};
        bus_stops_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        bus_stops.setAdapter(bus_stops_adapter);
        bus_stops.setClickable(true);
        bus_stops.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                Object o = bus_stops.getItemAtPosition(position);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnterAmbient(Bundle ambientDetails) {
        super.onEnterAmbient(ambientDetails);
        updateDisplay();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateAmbient() {
        super.onUpdateAmbient();
        updateDisplay();
    }

    @Override
    public void onExitAmbient() {
        updateDisplay();
        super.onExitAmbient();
    }

    private void updateDisplay() {
        if (isAmbient()) {

        } else {

        }
    }

    /*private void updateLocation() {
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            Log.println(Log.INFO,"Log","Got location successfully!");
            Log.println(Log.INFO, "LOG", bus_stops_adapter.toString());

            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            String url = "http://transportapi.com/v3/uk/bus/stops/near.json?lat=" + mLastLocation.getLatitude() + "&lon=" + mLastLocation.getLongitude() + "&app_key=" + TransportAPI_Key + "&app_id=" + TransportAPI_ID;

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.println(Log.INFO, "Log", "SUCCESSFULLY GOT API THING");
                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.println(Log.INFO, "Log", "FAILED??");
                }

            });
            queue.add(stringRequest);
        } else {
            Log.println(Log.INFO,"Log","Failed to get location!");
        }
    }*/

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},2542);
            return;
        }

        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(60)
                .setFastestInterval(30);

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, this)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull Result result) {
                        if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            Log.println(Log.INFO,"Log","It worked??");
                        } else {
                            Log.println(Log.INFO,"Log","It failed??");
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                    .removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.println(Log.INFO,"Log","Connection suspended");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.println(Log.INFO,"Log","Connection failed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the line

```
requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, this)
```

Where `this` is your `MainActivity`. However, [per the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener)), the third parameter must be a [LocationListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener), which your `MainActivity` does not implement.

You must implement the interface and override the `onLocationChanged` method.

```
public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged (Location location) {
    // Do something with the location
  }

...
}
```